# help in topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Consider the set $S = \{a, b, c\}$ of three elements, with the topology 
$U = (\phi, S, \{a\}, \{b\}, \{a,b\})$. Find a continuous path from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: The topology is not discrete.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that you want a continuous map $f$ from the interval $[0,1]$ into $S$ such that $f(0) = a$ and $f(1) = b$. A map $f$ is continuous if and only if pre-images of open sets are open.

Now we know that $f^{-1}(\{ a\} )$ needs to be open and should contain $0$. So let's take an open neighborhood of $0$, say $[0, 1/3)$ and set $f(t) = a$ if $t \in [0,1/3)$. Let us furthermore agree that if $t \notin [0,1/3)$, then $f(t) \neq a$. This would mean that $f^{-1}(\{ a \}) = [0,1/3)$, which is open in $[0,1]$.

Now we still need to define $f(t)$ for $t \in [1/3, 1]$, note that $[1/3,1]$ is *not* open, so we cannot simply set $f(t) = b$ for $t \in [1/3, 1]$...

I will leave the rest open to you, if you need any more help, please just comment on this answer and I can given more hints.

Comment: thanks @Peter it really helpful.Could I define $f(t)=b$ if $t\in (1/3,1]$

Comment: Yes, you could! That leaves us with the question f(1/3) = ?

Comment: Once you've completed the definition of $f$, I would recommend that you check that for every open set $U$ in $S$, we have that $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$.